# Convert scala json string to an object

Tags: json, scala, object

I need to convert a string json in an object using scala.

I tried this, but I cannot access the prop Name, for example

```
import scala.util.parsing.json._
val parsed = JSON.parseFull("""{"Name":"abc", "age":10}""")
```

How can I do to get an string json and convert to an object? Thanks

Comment: Do you need to use Scala standard library for JSON manipulation? Would third party library be acceptable for you?

Comment: What do you mean by "an object" ?

Comment: Have a look at this link http://www.furidamu.org/blog/2012/09/18/beautiful-json-parsing-in-scala/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

val parsed = JSON.parseFull("""{"Name":"abc", "age":10}""")
val parsed = JSON.parseFull(parsed)

try it

Comment: Ok. Converted. Now, how can I do to get the param "age", for example.
If I run in sbt console, I'm receiving an Option[Any]
scala> parsed
res29: Option[Any] = Some(Map(Name -> abc, age -> 10.0))

Comment: This does not compile... for several reasons. This doesn't work!